# Using LIKE on CONCATed columns from two seperate tables

Tags: mysql

I have these two tables and I would like to be able to search on brand.NAME and product.NAME as one string using LIKE. I have been unsuccessful using CONCAT from this in combination with JOINS so this is above my paygrade.

Is this even possible?

**Wanted behavior**

On search "NIKE sh"

Results:

```
NIKE Shoes
NIKE shirts
```

**product**

```
ID   | NAME   | brandID |
1    | Shoes  | 1       |
2    | pants  | 2       | 
3    | shorts | 3       |
4    | shirts | 1       | 
5    | socks  | 2       |
```

**brand**

```
ID   | NAME    |
1    | NIKE    |
2    | Adidas  |
3    | Hummel  |
```

Comment: Please add an example of the result you expect at least!

Comment: Please share what query you have tried.

Comment: Why don't you just do something like WHERE Product.Name LIKE "x" OR Brand.Name LIKE "x". Is it necessary to concat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to JOIN the two tables and then run the LIKE. One caveat: if you do a straight CONCAT, "Nike Shoes" will never match, because what you will have will be "NikeShoes".

SELECT ... FROM Product JOIN Brand ON (Product.BrandId = Brand.Id) WHERE CONCAT(Product.name, ' ', Brand.name) LIKE '%ike Sho%';

Edit: that said, I agree with the other posters - it would be much more advantageous to look into Brands and Products separately. Unless you have a "google like" search where the user may enter whatever he fancies -- but in that case I'd try to have the UI revised.

Comment: Actually this is the most accurate answer with the exception of switching brands and products this is 100% perfect. Had to change answer as this is the best and for other looking for same solution.

Answer (score 1):

First draft, a blind guess...

```
SELECT * FROM product
INNER JOIN brand
ON product.brandID = brand.id
WHERE product.name LIKE '%string%'
OR brand.name LIKE '%string%'
```

**Edited** to match change in the question...

```
SELECT * FROM product
INNER JOIN brand
ON product.brandID = brand.id
WHERE product.name + ' ' + brand.name LIKE '%string%'
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I do apologize for not stating my question clearer. I assure you it's only because of lack of knowledge to do so not laziness. I see the overhead but for the scale it's very much passable. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Are you saying that my *unrevised* answer was correct? If so, I'll change it back.

Comment: I've put back the original, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

```
.. where Product.name like '%pattern%' or Brand.name like '%pattern%'
```

Does that work?

Having said that, OR is expensive, so is a pattern search starting with a wild char. Both will cost you quite  a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELCT * FROM 
(SELECT P.NAME + B.NAME AS product_brand
FROM product AS P
INNER JOIN brand as B
ON
P.brandID = B.ID) SQ
WHERE
SQ.product_brand like '%whatever%'
```